# Can Crow's feet notation be mixed with UML profile for data modeling?

Tags: database, database-design, class-diagram

In ERD modeling, I know there are Chen notation or Crows feet notation. Also I know that ERD can be modeled using UML class diagrams where UML notation is used (1-1, 1-.* etc).
Hence I found this very confusing:
http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/database_engineering/database_keys.html

As it uses Crows feet notation with UML profile. I am really confused now and would appreciate any help to understand.

Comment: What don't you understand? There are a number of different notations used in UML and/or ER data modelling (Chen, Barker, IDEF1X, IE, etc).

Comment: Yes, but from I have read, UML profile uses UML notation for ERD(because its UML...). Crows feet displays information differently so I cannot see how both can be mixed as shown in the picture.

Comment: Different tools support different notations and software vendors don't necessarily follow standards. Sparx EA does allow crow's feet notation on UML diagrams - probably because it's something that many modellers are familiar with.

Comment: Any document that is understood is valid.